# Preposition to use with "satire"

Tags: phrase-usage

I was reading an article which included the sentence:

> He claimed that the letter was satire.

I scoffed and wanted to exclaim, "satire against *what*?" -- but I'm not sure that's the correct or most appropriate phrasing.

[Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=satire+against%2Csatire+for%2C+satire+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csatire%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csatire%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csatire%20of%3B%2Cc0) indicates that "satire of X" is most popular (between "against", "of" and "for"), but is one more correct than another? Are there meaningful differences for when I would use one vs. another?

Comment: ***Satire on*** appears to be the more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=satire+against%2Csatire+for%2Csatire+of%2Csatire+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csatire%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csatire%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csatire%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csatire%20on%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Your NGram pulls in many different contexts, many of which may favour one preposition over another. For example, usage is far more evenly split if we consider [*(someone) **wrote a satire** of/against (whatever was being satirised)*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wrote+a+satire+of%2Cwrote+a+satire+against&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrote%20a%20satire%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrote%20a%20satire%20against%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: you could also say "a satire" ... my read of the definitions in don't require satire of ... nor does my ear. I do agree the setence seems off but I think that the word used without an object should be "satirical" (he claimed that the letter was satirical") heres the dictionary: ADJECTIVE

1Containing or using satire.
‘a New York-based satirical magazine’
More example sentences
1.1 Sarcastic, critical, and mocking another's weaknesses.
‘his satirical sense of humour’ https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/satirical

Comment: See, this is why I asked you fine folk at SE :) @FumbleFingers, thanks for pointing that out. I see if I add Josh's suggestion to the [ngram query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wrote+a+satire+of%2Cwrote+a+satire+against%2Cwrote+a+satire+on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrote%20a%20satire%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrote%20a%20satire%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrote%20a%20satire%20on%3B%2Cc0) it's a clear winner.. interesting!

Comment: @whrrgarbl you can use a `*` in NGram to check what's the most common word: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wrote+a+satire+*